# Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocoder

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So I have some javascript that uses the google maps API V3 and uses the geocoder to obtain co ordinates from an address and display a map at those coordinates. It was working totally fine, but then I check it again a few days ago, and now instead of showing the proper map, it just shows a blank blue map, and doesnt let you zoom in or out or move the map. There doesnt appear to be any javascript errors or errors returning from google maps, so not really sure what could be causing this...

Heres an example of the problem: [Click Here](http://vietnamenus.com/restaurants/4P%27s-Pizza)

Anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using undocumented properties:

```
var center = results[0].geometry.location.Xa - 0.0062;
var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(center, results[0].geometry.location.Ya);
```

(geometry.Xa, geometry.Ya)

That is guaranteed to fail at some point when the version of the API changes.

Use the [documented properties (geometry.lat(), geometry.lng())](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)