# 'item.geometry.location.kb' and 'item.geometry.location.jb' returning undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using Google Maps to get an autocomplete list of cities.

I used to use *item.geometry.location.kb* as the longitude and *item.geometry.location.jb* as the latitude, but they are not defined since today/yesterday.

Apparently, one has to use *item.geometry.location.lng()* and *.lat()* instead.

I didn't know that and I have an app using *item.geometry.location.kb* and *jb* in [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) and the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)).

So my apps are not working any more.

Why has a change has been made and how can I revert to *kb* and *jb*?

```javascript
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(event) {

    var item = autocomplete.getPlace();

    curLon = item.geometry.location.kb;
    curLat = item.geometry.location.jb;

    // ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114797/google-maps-api-v3-only-showing-a-blank-map-when-using-the-geocder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use undocumented properties of the Google APIs.  They can and do change with every release.

*geometry.location* is a *[google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)* object, and the documented methods to get latitude and longitude are *.lat()* and *.lng()*.

Comment: Since I receive a JSON structure, I assumed I could use its 'public' interface.

Comment: Don't assume.  Read the documentation.  That documents the public (and invariant) interface.