# Add markers after removing them from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to add new markers after removing markers from Google maps. However, my code isn't doing what I expected. After the removal, no new marker could be added.

Code **snippet**:

```
function codeAddress(coordinates) {
        console.log("called");
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.lb,coordinates.mb);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng
            });
            markersArray[markerid] = marker;
            markerid++;
}
function deleteOverlays() {
        if (markersArray) {
          for (i in markersArray) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
          }              
        }
        markersArray = {};
        markerid = 0;
    }
function go(){
        var cMin = document.getElementById('costMin').value;
        var cMax = document.getElementById('costMax').value;
        var religion = document.getElementById('religion').value;                        

        // remove previous marker layer
        deleteOverlays();
        console.log(coorList.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < coorList.length; ++i){              

            //codeAddress();                

            if(religion != ""){
                if(coorList[i].cost1 >= cMin && coorList[i].cost1 <= cMax && coorList[i].religion.toLowerCase() ==religion.toLowerCase()){
                    codeAddress(coorList[i]);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(coorList[i].cost1 >= cMin && coorList[i].cost1 <= cMax){
                    codeAddress(coorList[i]);
                }
            }   

        }            
    }

<input id="costMin" type="textbox" >
<input id="costMax" type="textbox" >
<input id="religion" type="textbox" >
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go();">
```

When I placed a console.log("called") within the codeAddress() function, it seems like the function is not called at all after the click. If I get rid of deleteOverlays() from the go() function, the codeAddress will be called. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Post your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It looks like you are using [undocumented properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined/18088046#18088046) `coordinates.lb,coordinates.mb`, don't do that.