# Get object by position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My problem is that I have a function which will fill two input fields with latitude and longitude from google maps but when I get the coordinates I get them by their name, in this case "d" and "e". But these names keep changing on a weekly basis, so I have to manually change the values inside my function for this to work. Not sure if im the one causing them to change.

I would much rather get the values by their  position, in Python I could do something like this **latlng[0]** from a dictionary and get the first value, how could I do something similar in Javascript?

This is what I get when I run my commented part in my function.

```
{"d":58.3991706643976,"e":15.574407577514648}
```

Insert cordinates to input field function

```
function insertCoordinates(latlng) {

    // ---------------
    //latlng = JSON.stringify(latlng);
    //document.write(latlng);
    //----------------

    document.getElementById('start_lat').value = latlng["b"];
    document.getElementById('start_lng').value = latlng["d"];


}
```

Initialize function

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(XXXX, YYYYY),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        createMarker(map, event.latLng, "Click: "+event.latLng);
        insertCoordinates(event.latLng);
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [item.geometry.location.kb & item.geometry.location.jb returning undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined)

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`? `event` in `click` event handler is `MouseEvent` object with property `latLng` which is of type `LatLng`. Object `LatLng` has methods `lat()` and `lng()` to get values. It's better to use method `lat()` and `lng()` to set values in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But these names keep changing so I have to manually change the values inside my function for this to work. I would much rather get the values by their position...

They don't have a position. The properties in JavaScript objects have no order. These two objects are **exactly** identical in JavaScript:

```
a = {d: 1, e: 2};
b = {e: 2, d: 1};
```

Although many JavaScript engines will enumerate the names of the properties (for instance, in a `for-in` loop, or via `Object.keys`) in the order in which the properties were added to the object, that is not specified behavior, nor is it universal, nor should you be relying on the order the properties were added.

The real problem that needs solving here is that the property names are a moving target.

**Update**: And the reason they're a moving target is that they're not part of the public API. See the [`LatLng` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) in the Google documentation. You're not supposed to use the properties, which are internal to Google Maps; you use the `lat()` and `lng()` methods. (So when they change, it's probably because Google updates their code and runs it through their Closure Compiler again, which renames things to make them shorter unless they're marked to be exported — which of course, private internal properties won't be.)

Comment: Ok, but they seem change on a weekly basis, im not sure if im the one causing it because i can restart the server and the same values will work.

Comment: @Pierre: It's certainly not the Google API that's changing them weekly. My guess is that you're consuming something that's being "minified"/"compressed"/"packed" by a tool that renames property names to make them shorter. Any time your code changes and you rerun the tool, the names of those properties are liable to change. You'll want to track down the relevant tool and find out how you tell it to leave certain properties alone, and configure it to leave these alone so you have a reliable API to work with.

Comment: @Pierre: Ah, looks like you're trying to use internal properties of Google Maps. Stick to the documented API (see update above).