# Can I rely on the weekday_text object returned from Google Places API PlaceResult object?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

The `opening_hours.weekday_text` object returned in a PlaceResult object from Google Places API is not documented in the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

I cannot find any reference to `weekday_text` in the documentation. Given [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined) says '*Don't use undocumented properties of the Google APIs. They can and do change with every release'*, I am concerned that this could change in the future.

Can I rely on the `opening_hours.weekday_text` object in an application or should I use the `opening_hours.periods` object to generate open/close data?

Example result...

```
"opening_hours": {
"open_now": true,
"periods": [
  {
    "close": {
      "day": 1,
      "time": "0000",
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 1430089200000
    },
    "open": {
      "day": 0,
      "time": "0800",
      "hours": 8,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 1430031600000
    }
  }
  ...
],
"weekday_text": [
  "Monday: 8:00 am – 11:00 pm",
  "Tuesday: 8:00 am – 11:00 pm",
  "Wednesday: 8:00 am – 11:00 pm",
  "Thursday: 8:00 am – 11:00 pm",
  "Friday: 8:00 am – 12:00 am",
  "Saturday: 8:00 am – 12:00 am",
  "Sunday: 8:00 am – 12:00 am"
]
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've updated the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details) to include details of the weekday_text field.

Comment: It seems that many times it's null, and yet the other field that tells you whether it's opened or not - isn't. How come? How could it know if it's currently opened or not, if it doesn't know when it's opened? Also, how come there is no known format for the times it's opened?