# Google.Maps.Event settings - Va versus Xa

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent

I am using an Event Listener that refer to the `relatedTarget` variable for Firefox or the `toElement` variable for Chrome and IE. But since I made that part of the code the parent variable changed. Why?

For example, before today I needed to use `evt.Va.toElement` to refer to the `toElement` variable but since this morning I need to use `evt.Xa.toElement`. Why did it change?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,"mouseout",function(evt){ // Mouseout
  if(evt.Xa.toElement){ // For Chrome and IE
    if(evt.Xa.toElement.id != "idName"){
     // Do something
    }
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use `toElement` or `relatedTarget` and be certain that it will always work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114797/google-maps-api-v3-only-showing-a-blank-map-when-using-the-geocder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evt.Xa is an undocumented property, and shouldn't be used for anything, it could change with any release of the API (the closure compiler reassigns the undocumented properties with each release).  Only *documented* properties are safe to use in production code.

Comment: Is there a better way to know the FromElement and the ToElement without using this evt.Xa/evt.Va?

Comment: Those aren't documented at all (at least that I could see), which means that they can and will change with every release until they are documented.  You could request an [enhancement](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) which makes them available.

Comment: That is another question. If/When you create it, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.