# Google Map JS API changed event.latLng.* property names

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Did Google Maps just changed the property names from `event.latLng.d` to `event.latLng.A` (Latitude) and from `event.latLng.e` to `event.latLng.k` (Longitude)?

I just noticed cause an entire webapp function just broke down and I was like 2 hours looking for it until I decided to log responses from Google Maps. It also changed on `TextSearch` from **Places Library**

The question would be why? did they notified? is this a normal thing? give me something please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google.Maps.Event settings - Va versus Xa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816294/google-maps-event-settings-va-versus-xa)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh I understand now, those properties are supposed to be **private** attributes. Thanks again Javascript...

**Answer**: correct way of getting latitude and longitude would be `latLng.lat()` and `latLng.lng()`

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering for the longest time why the attribute variable names were so weird and thought it was due to minified code or something, but it was this all along. Going to make my code much more readable.